# how to check if map key matches a string in freemarker?

Tags: string, dictionary, freemarker

I am trying to check if a key of a map in freemarker matches a particular string. How can I do that?

```
<#if (list_map.id)!?matches(("abc"))>
    you matched ...
</#if>
```

but the above doesn't work in freemarker. It says matches expects a string. How can I convert  list_map.id to a string ? is there any toString() method available in freemarkeR?

Comment: What's the type of `id`? People usually want to match strings against regular expressions. (Also what's up with the two `!`-s and the double parentheses? Some of those must be redundant.)

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is a number, then probably you want `list_map.id?c` to render it to computer-format string.

Comment: id is a string in this case. not a number. number can be automatically be converted to string but i get this error --> Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string

Comment: I basically wanted to check if "id" key has the value "abc" .

Comment: So what's the actual type when the error occurs? (If the error doesn't tell, probably you are using an old FreeMarker.)

Comment: so the type id is evaluated to a sequence. My console says this --> but this evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence):

Comment: I guess the `id` isn't supposed to be a list or array or something of that sort, and that's you real problem then. Or is it?

Comment: nope id is a string. not a list or array etc. That's the problem as in? din't get u. id is basically one of the keys of my map. and I just need to check if value of key "id" is equal to "abc". What's the best way to do that?

Comment: In meant the type of the value that's associated to `"id"` in that `Map`. Even the variable suggests that that `Map` contains `List` values, not `String`-s. (`"id"` is a string, yes, but the associated value isn't, so it seems.) (Also if you really just want to check for equality, use `==`.)